# jQuery trigger click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function is_numeric(n){
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // Est-ce que on doit forcer l'ouverture d'un asset en particulier ?
        var Hash = window.location.hash;
        var Triggered = false;

        if(Hash != undefined && Hash != ''){
            Hash = Hash.substring(2);

            if(is_numeric(Hash) === true && Hash > 0){
                Triggered = true;
                jQuery('.show-container[data-id="'+Hash+'"]').trigger('click');
            }
        }

        if(Triggered === false){
            jQuery('.show-container:first-child').trigger('click');
        }

        jQuery('.show-container').bind('click', function(e){
            //  On empêche l'action par défaut du lien
            e.preventDefault();

            if(ContainerEl.css('display') == 'none'){
                ContainerEl.show(0, function(){
                    SubContainerEl.slideDown(300, function(){
                        // Other code there...
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // On cache le tout
                SubContainerEl.slideUp(300, function(){
                    ContainerEl.hide(0);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the html

```
<h4 class="heading"><a class="show-container" data-id="1" href="javascript:void(0);">BC600 | <span id="assign_count_1">0</span> / 5</a></h4>
<div id="asset-data-1" data-ajax-loaded="false" class="row-fluid" style="display: none;">
    <div data-container="true" class="span12" style="display: none; height: 310px; overflow: auto;"></div>
</div>

<h4 class="heading"><a class="show-container" data-id="2" href="javascript:void(0);">Ultrabook HP3608 | <span id="assign_count_2">9</span> / 25</a></h4>
<div id="asset-data-2" data-ajax-loaded="false" class="row-fluid" style="display: none;">
    <div data-container="true" class="span12" style="display: none; height: 310px; overflow: auto;"></div>
</div>
```

The thing is, when `window.location.hash` is not empty, I want to read it and extract the information. The information will be something like `#a2` or `#a23`... the number is the `AssetID`.

If I see a valid ID, I want to trigger the click, if not I want to trigger the first one by default.

This doesn't work and the console give me no error. I placed some alert to check if the script was going far enough and yes, he does but the trigger do nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please consolidate your code to the specific issue?

Comment: Also please post your generated HTML (not the PHP).

Comment: please post the HTML that your PHP generates, not the PHP itself.

Comment: @JoshMein I told you in my post. The trigger doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to trigger the click before it has been bound. Your code should be like this:

```
// This section orignally appeared after the triggering of the click
jQuery('.show-container').bind('click', function(e){
    // Your code
});

if(Triggered === false){
    jQuery('.show-container:first-child').trigger('click');
}
```

Also as a note, depending on what version of jQuery you are using, bind is deprecated and should be replaced by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
jQuery('.show-container').on('click', function(e){
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: It's working, thanks. Couldn't believe I forgot that... Your right I should be using on. In the code you don't see I use it but not there. Thanks for the tip. I switched from an older version to 1.7.2 and I have to stop using bind lol... thnaks !

Comment: Your welcome! Thanks for consolidating your code! It made it a whole lot easier to see the problem.

Comment: Yea I understand. Lot of code make it hard to understand the problem faster then what it is really... but I sometime forget that the people who will read it aren't... me so it's a different point of view... Thanks for helping sir!

Comment: I should be using `jQuery('.show-container:eq(0)').trigger('click');` instead of `jQuery('.show-container:first-child').trigger('click');` also in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Hash is a String;
is_numeric() will return true even if you pass it a String like '20' or '55'.

You need to convert the string to number.

A way to do this is:

```
var Hash = 'a23';
Hash = Hash.substring(2);

var actualNumber = Number(Hash); // Here you convert the string to number
```

This should work.

Comment: I found another issue in your code. If your hash is something like: 'a23', 'a2', 'a1000', using substring(2) will only get all the characters after first 2 like this:  '3', 'empty string', '000' (for my examples); You should use substring(1, Hash.length);

Comment: No. Because `window.location.hash` also return the hash tag at first.

Comment: You could use console.log(Hash > 0); exactly before 'if(is_numeric(Hash) === true && Hash > 0)'. It will return false if Hash is not a number and this way you can see that this check is valid and something else is causing the problem.